# HOW to EXIT using "start" in batch files of MSDOS

Tags: batch-file, exit

I want to copy some files into diffent USB disks, and want to use START to open several consoles as follows:

```
start copy a.txt h:
start copy a.txt i:
start copy a.txt j:
```

But everytime I run the batch file, there are 3 consoles without exiting.
How can I realize this EXIT function **WITHOUT** using 3 batch files and "call" commands as:

*copy.bat:*

```
call a.bat
call b.bat
call c.bat
exit
```

and three called batch files as:

*a.bat:*

```
start copy a.txt h:
exit
```

*b.bat:*

```
start copy a.txt i:
exit
```

*c.bat:*

```
start copy a.txt j:
exit
```

I already tried this, but it DOES NOT work:

```
start copy a.txt h: && exit
start copy a.txt i: && exit
start copy a.txt j: && exit
```

Comment: Edited my answer, this one works :)

Comment: Just out of curiosity; why is using `call` not an option?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to escape && so it becomes part of the command executed by start and not the parent batch file.

```
start copy a.txt h: ^&^& exit
```

To close the new console even if there are errors you can do:

```
start "" "%comspec%" /c copy a.txt h:
```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know you had to escape the &'s.

Comment: Thanks, the first case is helpful and useful! I didn't know the escape before either.

Comment: `start` with the `/b` parameter will prevent a window to be created.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `start` to start a new cmd window and close it once the command has been run like this:

```
start cmd /c copy a.txt h:
```